# Reputation not changing after votes

Tags: bug, reputation, post-issues

I have 3,825 reputation on Stack Overflow. If someone down-votes or up-votes then the reputation count is not changing.

I do not know if it's bug.

see image if they have reputation limitation then why they allowed me for more than 300 rep.

[image]

Comment: What specific question is it? Community-wiki questions do not geenrate reputation.

Comment: And it's because you've hit rep-cap for today. 250 reputation so far. Good job.

Comment: @J.Steen i don't know but it always comes up with not meet quality standard message and tried quote-formatting and it immediatley posted question..sorry

Comment: Well, one thing you could do is try writing your personal "I" as capital even in the middle of sentences. "i am facing problem" above should be "I am facing a problem". For instance. Also, don't use excessive formatting where none is needed. =)

Comment: @J.Steen hey take a look i score more than 300 tomorrow but that time they did not blocked me...so why today.??? may be because today is Friday..

Comment: Your reputation from VOTES is capped at 200 per day. You can still get reputation from answer-acceptance, bounties, et c.

Comment: @J.Steen; it should be _"I am facing **a** problem"_, however, the entire sentence is superfluous.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Merely an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've hit the rep cap already today. You can only get 200 reputation per day, *but more via bounties, accepts, and administrative changes* such as undoing serial downvoting directed against you. This resets each day at midnight, UTC.

[image]

However, you should also remember that community-wiki questions do not generate reputation, except via bounties.

Comment: if you forget then check for tomorrow counting..

Comment: @J.Steen Fixed.

Comment: @DipeshParmar Yesterday* not tomorrow.

Comment: @BackinaFlash ohh yeah..must be cause of not sleep for a days...sorry but can you explain it to me..?

Comment: It's explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work). Specifically, **You can earn a maximum of +200 reputation from upvotes and suggested edits in any given day. Accepted answers and bounties are counted separately.**

Comment: @BackinaFlash perfect answer now i got it....please post this comment as answer i will accept it.

Comment: It's already perfectly readable in that linked question, as well as answered above. =)